# What kind of analysis is done in front wheel plane?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, flight-instruments, ground-operations

I’m not sure how to describe this as a question… So here is an image:

[image]

1. What is the device? (marked in red)
2. What could the ground crew be analyzing near the wheel (marked in green)

They’ve been at it for quite a while

Comment: Welcome to Aviation. As for your second question, it could be one of *many* things, but there's no way of *knowing* by just a distant photo, so it's out of this site's scope.

Comment: When you see several  people standing observing someone doing something like that, it's usually a training or demonstration session of some kind.  Nose gear servicing perhaps.